# window.location.href not working in form-html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

window.location.href is not redirecting the user.
I have tried with return true also

Form Code:-

```html
<form method="POST" name="main_form" onsubmit="login()">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="pwd">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Login():-

```js
function login() {
    var email = document.main_form.email.value;
    var pwd = document.main_form.pwd.value;
    if (email == 'example@example.com' && pwd == 'example123') {
        sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
        window.location.href = './index.html';
        return false;
```

Comment: You need to do `onsubmit="return login()"` for the return false to work

Comment: And move return false outside the if

Comment: Thanks it worked @mplungjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from not storing userid and password in the page, you need to use
`onsubmit="return login()"` and

```
function login() {
  var email = document.main_form.email.value;
  var pwd = document.main_form.pwd.value;
  if (email == 'example@example.com' && pwd == 'example123') {
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
    window.location.href = './index.html';
  }
  return false;
}
```

Better is using event listeners:

```
document.querySelector("form[name=main_form]").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  const email = this.email.value; // "this" is the form due to using function in the eventListener. Use a fat arrow and you need e.target
  const pwd = this.pwd.value;
  if (email == 'example@example.com' && pwd == 'example123') {
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
    window.location.href = './index.html';
  }
});
```